# Pandas spreadsheet like tabular

Tags: python, pandas

consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'split_1':[1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1],
    'split_2':[3,3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,3],
    'var_1':[1,2,4,3,2,4,2,2,1,2],
    'var_2':[4,2,2,2,1,5,4,3,4,3],
})
```

What I want to achive is a tabular similar (or exactly) like this:

[image: Example]

I come pretty far by playing with the groupby and agg method.

```
grp = df.groupby(['split_1','split_2'])

tab1 = grp['var_1'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.max, np.min, np.size])
tab2 = grp['var_2'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.max, np.min, np.size])

tab = tab1.append(tab2)
```

This seems hackish... I can't seem to find a way (or the right place to look in the docs) to properly group and aggregate the data in the way I want.

Is there a proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a tad cleaner:

```
In [15]: grp = df.groupby(['split_1','split_2'])

In [16]: grp.agg([np.mean, np.median, np.max, np.min, np.size]).stack(0)
Out[16]: 
                           mean  median  amax  amin  size
split_1 split_2                                          
1       3       var_1  1.333333       1     2     1     3
                var_2  3.666667       4     4     3     3
        4       var_1  2.000000       2     2     2     1
                var_2  1.000000       1     1     1     1
2       3       var_1  2.666667       2     4     2     3
                var_2  2.333333       2     3     2     3
        4       var_1  3.000000       3     4     2     3
                var_2  3.666667       4     5     2     3
```

Basically, there's no need to apply the set of functions to the two groups separately and append the results together. That's essentially what group by is doing: split, apply (separately) and combine.

Comment: Thank you! Addition: I was able to get my exact format with this approach and calling ```reset_index()``` on the DataFrame.